# Significant delay in generation of View (Viewed Table) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a few **Personnel Details** tables in a database in SQL Server 2014. There is a view that pick up selected data from these tables by implementing a few joins.

One condition to select the row is if its columnn `isActive = 1` in `NominalRoll` table. There is a report in SQL Server Reporting Server that calls this view and displays the PDF.

Until now the `NominalRoll` table had 1 million rows out of which 75% had `isActive = 1`. The report generation was taking up to 1 minute for display.

Recently due to some requirements, the `isActive` column has been updated and now only 5% of the rows have `isActive = 1`. Strangely enough, since then the report is taking up to 4 minutes for display even when the rows to be display have greatly reduced.

On viewing the **ExecutionLog2** entries, it is found out that the time for fetching data from the view has significantly increased. Please help, it is a live system.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the indexes on the tables that the view uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is not materialized by default. That means that when you query the view, the engine is executing its definition.

You can try few things here:

1. Materialized the view creating an [index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) on it - the view data will be automatically updated when underlying data is changed and it acts as a table (so, it will looks like you are performing `SELECT` from a normal SQL table). Note, that a lot of [stuffs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15#additional-requirements) are not supported in indexed views.
2. You are selecting only 5% of the rows filtering by `isActive=1` - that's sound like good candidate for creating [filter index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#filtered-indexes). It will help the engine to make better estimations about the data it is going to work with.

The above changes need a little bit more work and require DDL operations. If you are not allowed to change the schema you can share the view definition in order to get some help for optimizing the T-SQL. Actually, it is always best to start with optimizing the T-SQL, before going to DDL changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a life saver. **Filtered Index** solved the problem..